# How to update schema in SQL Server database using Active Records and nhibernate?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have winforms application which uses nhibernate and active records to access the database. My question is how do I update the database schema through the application? The `CreateSchema` method deletes the database and creates a new one. Is there anyway to update just few parts of the database through some method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use schemaupdate, providing you have the configuration

```
 public void CanUpdateDatabase()
    {
        SchemaUpdate su = new SchemaUpdate(config);
        su.Execute(true, true);
    }
```

it works depending on the db dialect ( in my experience works well with MSSQL+Oracle )